# Can't input in command prompt when using keytool to generate key pair (public and private keys) and a signing certificate

Tags: android, cmd, keytool, keyboard-input

I can't provide any input from my keyboard or from the on-screen keyboard when using keytool to generate key pair (public and private keys) and a signing certificate.

This problem occurs only when executing this command not in any other commands.
I tried using running command from .bat file but still can't provide any input.
[image]

**The only input i can provide is enter(button).

So should i go forward by again providing enter(button)?**

Note: I am referring Oreilly Android Application Development 2009.pdf
Web version: http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect17_d1e6459.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you can't provide password? It doesn't show you any character when you type password and it is correct. Did you try print e.g. '123' as password and '456' as re-enter password? Does it say they don't match?

Comment: Thanks!! It was taking input but I didn't notice it. I was kind of spooked because the cursor didn't move at all!! :D